# How to output an image from

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to upload a local image in the project using before but it's not visible. the image is in the same folder as the files.
images from the link from the Internet work fine, but local ones do not(. Please push in which direction to go))

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div className="qrt"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
css

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.qrt {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.qrt::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("./image.jpeg");
}.
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-rhodes-uzdk0k Link to sunbox

Comment: move the image to `public` folder so it can be considered as a static asset

Comment: @mocherfaoui unfortunately it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: what didn't work exactly? I checked the codesandbox and it worked after you moved the image to `public`